# MySQL: rounding percentages correctly

Tags: mysql, rounding, percentage

I have a table `t(int, float, float, float)` in MySQL database, with the following values:

| id | v1 | v2 | v3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.25 | 0.75 | 0 |
| 2 | 0.125 | 0 | 0.875 |

It is guaranteed that v1+v2+v3==1 for each row.

*Note: v1, v2 and v3 are floats so in some cases v1+v2+v3 may be 1 +/- 1E-38*

I need to generate integer percentages on the output (i.e. integers between 0 and 100), that would be adding up to 100 for each record, and at the same time that would represent source values as closely as possible.

For the above data sample, the expected output would be either:

| id | p1 | p2 | p3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25 | 75 | 0 |
| 2 | 13 | 0 | 87 |

Or:

| id | p1 | p2 | p3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25 | 75 | 0 |
| 2 | 12 | 0 | 88 |

(both above outputs are acceptable)

My current solution:

Step 1: calculate `p1tmp = round(100*v1), p2tmp = round(100*v2), p3tmp = round(100*v3)`

Step 2: calculate:

```
p1 = CASE
    WHEN p1tmp = GREATEST(p1tmp, p2tmp, p3tmp) AND GREATEST(p1tmp, p2tmp, p3tmp) > LEAST(p1tmp, p2tmp, p3tmp)
    THEN 100 - p2tmp - p3tmp ELSE p1tmp END AS p1,
p2 = CASE
    WHEN p2tmp = GREATEST(p1tmp, p2tmp, p3tmp) AND GREATEST(p1tmp, p2tmp, p3tmp) > LEAST(p1tmp, p2tmp, p3tmp)
    THEN 100 - p1tmp - p3tmp ELSE p2tmp END AS p2,
p3 = CASE
    WHEN p3tmp = GREATEST(p1tmp, p2tmp, p3tmp) AND GREATEST(p1tmp, p2tmp, p3tmp) > LEAST(p1tmp, p2tmp, p3tmp)
    THEN 100 - p1tmp - p2tmp ELSE p3tmp END AS p3
```

While mathematically correct, the above solution is not very elegant. The code is convoluted, unreadable and not easily extendable to a case with 4 or 5 values (my current requirement is 4 values really i.e. v1, v2, v3, v4 but it may change in the future).

I tried applying round-to-the-nearest-even approach but it only worked for a pair of variables (i.e. v1,v2, not v1,v2,v3).

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: Is it not guaranteed that one v will be zero?

Comment: Nope. Any number of Vs can be non-zero for any single record.

Answer (score 0):

MSSQL solution, but may be easely adopted.
-- make a pivot

```
declare @id int
set @id =4 -- take a single row data

create table #row(x float, procent int, col int);
insert into #row
 select v1,0,1  from t where id = @id union all
 select v2,0,2  from t where id = @id union all 
 select v3,0,3  from t where id = @id;


with cte as 
(select x, 
case when x != (select max(x) from #row) then ROUND(x*100,0) else ROUND(x*100,0,1) end x2
from #row )

select * from cte -- unpivoto

drop table #row
```